# Convert mm-dd-yy format to unix time stamp?

Tags: php, unix, timestamp

I've spent hours on google and Stack Exchange. For the life of me I havent found a working solution and i'm not sure why.

I simply need to get 06-15-14 formatted and into a unix timestamp. I've tried all sorts of things. mktime, strptime, strto...often nothing spits out or I get 12-31-69

I also need to get single digit dates IE - 6-15-14   or 6-5-14

```
$chance = "come on 06-15-14";

if (preg_match("/[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9][0-9]/", $chance, $matches)) {
echo "Match was found <br />";
echo $matches[0];


$a = strptime('$matches[0]', '%m-%d-%y');
echo $a;


}
else {
echo "nope";
}
```

Comment: You are using `strptime`. Presumably you have read the documentation, which includes a link to [`date_parse_from_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) and says it is recommended. Why not follow that recommendation? It would take much less than hours.

Comment: your example works fine

Answer (score 0):

assuming your regex is correct,

```
$a = strptime('$matches[0]', '%m-%d-%y');
```

should be

```
$a = strptime($matches[0], '%m-%d-%y');
```

without the quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
 list($month, $day, $year) = split('-', $matches[0]);
 $timestamp = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
```

that seems to solve the issue